# SOAP UI: Getting Error getting response; null when trying to connect to Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, soapui

I am trying to connect to Microsoft sql server 2018 from SOAP ui by creating a JDBC Request, but geeting Error getting response; null in logs.

Note: i have added mssql-jdbc-7.2.2.jre11 to ext folder in SOAP UI.

[External Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPLQN.png)

[SOAP-UI 5.5 JDBC Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hnJe.png)

Driver: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

Connection String: jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost; databaseName=Amazon;integratedSecurity=true;

Query: select * from userbase

Comment: Please update your question with a sample of your code

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, updated the question accordingly...could you please  help  me on this

Comment: Please try connecting and querying in a Groovy script test step and share the output

Comment: i got the following error while running groovy scrip//  java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost; databaseName=Amazon;integratedSecurity=true; error at line:

Comment: So now you can troubleshoot. Either it is the wrong jar version, or it is not loading properly, or your connection string is not right. Also you are using integrated security which may or may not work with SoapUI

Comment: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDriver has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0 error at line: 3.. There is some issue with JRE need help in identifying root cause

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2018** version - we have 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017 and 2019 - take your pick

Answer (score 0):

I don't use the JDBC step in SoapUI, but rather do my database steps in a Groovy script test step.

I also have had more success with the [jTDS](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.jtds/jtds/1.3.1) driver for MS-SQL.

A sample connection string with domain authentication/integrated security is:

```
def conn = Sql.newInstance("""jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://SERVERNAME:1433/dbname;
                 useLOBs=false;
                 instance=SERVERNAME;
                 autoCommit=true;
                 useNTLMv2=true;
                 domain=MYDOMAIN",
                 "MyUser", "MyPassword", "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver""")
```

Then:

```
myDB.eachRow("select * from userbase;"){
    //do something with the data
}
```

I would also suggest that you select specific columns, not *
From there you can put the data in a file or populate property values or whatever.